# Coloring cell background when cell.textLabel.text string isEqualTo

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to color the background yellow when the string that is put into the cell equals a given word. I have been googling and asking friends and so far I have come up with this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSRange flash = [[newsArray objectAtIndex:rad] rangeOfString: @"FLASH:"];
    if(flash.length > 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    }
```

This does work but... it colors the wrong background. The one after the one I want to be colored. I have been told to put the coloring code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath instead but then it doesn't color anything.

Well that is it!

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be the best place to do this. Would be great to see the code you used there as this should work.

Comment: I moved this code to cellForRowAtIndexPath and that does not work.

Comment: Can you show the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath concerning these cells?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm - what's 'rad' in that code ([newsArray objectAtIndex:rad]) ?

Nowhere do I see you make use of 'indexPath' to determine if you should highlight that particular cell.

Comment: rad is my int that is indexPath.row. I need to do like that due to that I need to read 2 lines at a time not every line.

Comment: And sure this works but it colors the wrong cell... the cell before the one I need to color. That is my problem.

Comment: We're missing some code, no?  rad isn't defined in the code snippet, and I can't see how you're taking into account the indexPath that's being passed to the function.